# Magento2 Multiple Blocks returns same object

Tags: magento2, cms-block

```
{{block class="Class_path" name="xyz" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" id="6"}}

{{block class="Class_path" name="xyz" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" id="7"}}

{{block class="Class_path" name="xyz" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" id="8"}}
```

I have used these three blocks in my CMS page but when I get the id, I am always getting `6`

What I understand from this is my first block is stored or cached and its always returned

I changed the block name to different values but got the same result.

I changed the values to this and still getting the same result.

```
 {{block class="Class_path" name="xyz1" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" menuid="6"}}

 {{block class="Class_path" name="xyz2" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" menuid="7"}}

 {{block class="Class_path" name="xyz3" template="Package_Module::file.phtml" menuid="8"}}
```

Comment: how do you get the id?

Comment: @amit Block names should be unique per page. Directly from Magento 2's layout dev guide "Name that can be used to address the block to which this attribute is assigned. The name must be unique per generated page. If not specified, an automatic name will be assigned in the format ANONYMOUS_n" More information at; http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: I am using `$this->getMenuid()` in my block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in magento some blocks are cached like `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` you can use below code for remove your block from cache. Insert below code in your block file.

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this happens, but I can give you some debug advice.
the directives `{{block...}}` are parsed in [`Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter::blockDirective()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php#L367).
This method interprets the parameters in 2 ways, in this order:

- if there is a `class` attribute then it instantiates the class and calls setters for the other parameters from the class it has just instantiated. But it ignores the parameters `['class', 'id', 'output']`.
- if there is no `class` attribute then it will search for `id` and load the cms block with the id you provide.

In your case, the `id` parameter should be ignored completely because you have the `class` parameter specified.
Check where do you get that `id` 6 from.

Comment: Actually I mistyped `menuid` with `id` in my question